# Try/catch not working with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, try-catch, laravel-5.4

I know there are a lot of answers there about this question but none of them really helped me.

```
// update name

Route::put('/profile/update', function(Request $request){
$name = $request->input('name');

   try{
         echo DB::table('users')->where('id',Auth::id())->update(['name' => $name]);
      }
   catch(\Exception $e){
     // do task when error
      echo $e->get_message();
   }
});
```

I have also tried delete method but that is also not working can you please figure out what is going on.
thanks.

Comment: is this the route file `web.php`? why there's `});`? give a description please to what you want to do and what you tried and the issue

Comment: yes that is web.php file and what do you mean by why there's }); i am testing this method so thats why I am using direct function.

Comment: ok. your issue is it's always returning `1` isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your code it seems like the code will never hit the catch which is nothing to do with laravel actually. your issue is a **SQL** one.

you're trying to update a record and updating a none-existing row will never fail in SQL. so I suggest to handle the case manually by checking the result value and replacing the **try** and **catch** with **if else**

BTW @Learner is 100% right about `get_message()` it's not in laravel as I know replace it in the future with `getMessage()`

Answer (score 7):

### 2020 Update

Laravel mostly uses camelCase for nomenclature so use:

```
   catch(\Exception $e){
     // do task when error
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

If not then just dump full `$e` to see it through:

```
    catch(\Exception $e){
       // do task when error
       dd($e);
    }
```

snake_case nomenclature is only used for table names in Laravel.

Comment: sorry but this is not the answer it is a suggestion

Comment: @Khan Shahrukh, Excuse me? :)) Dude `get_message()` is not used to take error message in Laravel. `getMessage()` is the right method..It will resolve OP's problem, idk what you are talking about. In my opinion anything which solves the problem explained in question is mentioned as answer - lol

Comment: In my case get_message() was just an undefined function which makes 0 sense here but i placed it to only test that if catch is being executed but catch block is never executed.. May be an SQL issue ...

Answer (score 6):

in my case, I must use `\Throwable` instead of `\Exception`

```
try {
   //code 
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
     dd($e);
}
```

Comment: same for me on Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Change `echo $e->get_message();` to `echo $e->getMessage();`, Exception class dose not have get_message() function.